# Lumen: failed to open stream: Permission denied in .../vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, permission-denied, vendor

My OS is ubuntu 16.04 and I am running Lumen 5.5.
When I try to run the app in the browser I get an error 500:[image]

and I am getting that error in my /var/log/nginx:

```
2017/10/09 06:51:26 [error] 1063#1063: *132 FastCGI sent in stderr: 
"PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: 
 The stream or file "/home/ila/vhosts/dref_api.com/storage/logs/lumen.log"
 could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
 home/ila/vhosts/dref_api.com/
 vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
```

Permission in `storage/` is :[image]

Permissions in `vendor/ and all monolog/ sub files` are :[image]

So, I think could apply `sudo chmod -R guo+w /vendor` but I dont know if it would works or even if it is a good practice.

How are you solving this issue?

Comment: yes, it only worked after I apply 777 for storage.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like Storage folder doesnt have permission to write log files so
you can run

```
    chmod -R o+w projectname/storage
   chmod -R o+w projectname/bootstrap
```

if you are using nginx then  you need to use nginx user permission like below

```
sudo chown -R nginx:root storage
sudo chown -R nginx:root bootstrap
```